# Adding Class to specific item

Tags: jquery

**jQuery**

```
$('#history-years-menu li a[href='+hTab+']').addClass("selected");
```

**html**

```
<ul>
                <li><a href="#1">1980</a></li>
                <li><a href="#2">1950</a></li>
                <li><a href="#3">1960</a></li>
                <li><a href="#4">1970</a></li>
                <li><a href="#5">1980</a></li>
                <li><a href="#6">1990</a></li>
                <li><a href="#7">2000</a></li>
                <li><a href="#8">2010</a></li>
            </ul>
```

**Active State**

```
<li class="selected"><a href="#1">1980</a></li>
```

if hTab was equal to #3 how would I be able to change my jquery above to select the href of #3?

Comment: The code you have seems to work fine, but it adds the class to the `<a>` not the `<li>`. Is that the problem or is it something else?

Comment: Isn't `hTab` the `href`? I don't get the question

Comment: hTab is dynamic and changes depending on which <a> is clicked

Comment: the addClass needs to be added to the <li> not the <a>

Comment: And what do you want to retrieve exactly? As the `#3`'s `href` = `hTag` = `#3` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To apply the `.selected` class to `li` you have to go one level up from the `a`:

```
$('#history-years-menu li a[href=' + hTab + ']').parent().addClass("selected");
```

Answer (score 2):

To add the class to the `<li>` use:

```
$('#history-years-menu li a[href=' + hTab + ']').parent().addClass("selected");
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/mTwVp/)**